# In ios library not found for -lcurl issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

When i run my project this error comes

library not found for -lcurl

[image]

Comment: please don't post logs as screenshots, it's barely readable. Instead copy & paste the contents into the question. You can copy the entire log or individual lines from this window.

Comment: What were you doing when this happened? Did you add a library and miss some dependencies?

Comment: Did you download from GitHub or the zip from Cocos2d-x.org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. I removed "\" in the start of `search paths` which is located under the `build setting` tab